# Pick RGB Color Pixel from an Image In Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to develop an application, which can pick a hex code color from a pixel of image. I found WriteAbleBitmap, but i don't understand how to use it to get the pixel and convert to RGB color then to Hex Code. Because in Codeplex i found, WriteAbleBitmapEx.GetPixel(10,20), i try to do that, but nothing happened. Could you bring me an Example about getting RGB color from image pixel? or anything else which explained about that.? Please :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/), this open source library adds a `GetPixel` method to `WriteableBitmap`, which will do exactly what you want.

Comment: hmmh... with a same case i create it on Windows Form, i can use System.Drawing, get pixel, get color RGB and convert it to Hex Code. But, using WriteableBitmapEx are so complicated.. is there any example of GetPixel method?